# Looking for a historic chess game

Tags: famous-games, kasparov, capablanca

I'm looking for an historic chess game, and I don't remember if Capablanca or Kasparov played it. In it, both queens are face to face and neither let pass the other one, for almost 7 or 10 movements, in the middle of the board. I remember saw it on chessgames.com in 2005.

The queens moved horizontally, 1 or 2 spots. One was in the above row and the second one in the bottom, for e.g. the black queen in the 5th row and the white queen in the 4th row. So neither can't go forward, as they are blocking each other. I'm not sure if it was Capablanca or Kasparov, only about 70% sure.

Comment: Are you sure about either Capablanca or Kasparov?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "queens are face to face" and "neither let pass the other one"?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the meaning of "neither let pass the other one"? Does it mean that the queens move away from the other queen's attack, to avoid an exchange?

Comment: Are you sure it's an actual game and not a composition? https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDsNd.png

Comment: If you know python, there might be a way to use a chess library and brute force through all games in a database like TWIC. Then represent a board and play the moves on it, stopping when the queens are blocking each other in the centre, and if one of the opponents are Kasparov or Capablanca (or some other elite player).

Comment: @Leandro yes, is on the middle of the board with more pieces

Comment: I extracted 3166 games by Capablanca or Kasparov and examined all of those in which a black Queen on the fifth rank was opposite a white Queen on the fourth rank. None of those games exhibited the characteristics described. Possibly either the player or the ranks have been mis-remembered.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Python and code it to sift through Capablanca or Kasparov games. When there is a position where the queens oppose in the center, make the program put it to the side. Then, you can look through the games until you find the one you want.

If you don't know how to use Python, you could get someone else to help you, or to get a program with the same function from online.

Comment: Note that you need to download the Python software before you can run the programs.

Answer (score 1):

[Chess Query Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_Query_Language) is a tool you can use to search for games like these in your database of games of choice. It shouldn't be too hard to do this- certainly easier than the (good!) suggestion of Python by others